# Drop down menu with ASP.NET MVC 4 and EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create drop down menu in MVC4 (Entity Framework, code first). My aim is to prepare value in classes so I don't need additional programing on control page.

```
public class Prefix
{
    [Key]
    public int PrefixID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string PrefixName { get; set; }
}
public class People
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PrefixID")]
    public Prefix Prefix { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PrefixID { get; set; }       

    public string FullName // this isn't working
    {
        get
        {
            return Prefix.PrefixName +" " + FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }    
    }
}

public class PersonSalary
{
    [Key]
    public int SalaryId { get; set; }
    //...

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeID")]
    public Person HEmployee {get;set;}

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
}
```

Code in SalaryController:

```
ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.People, "PersonID", "FullName", personsalary.EmployeeID);
```

On SalaryController I can get drop down menu with values "Name Surname" but I want **"Prefix.Name Name Surname"**. For example "Mr John Doe", etc. Current code returns error:

> Object reference not set to instance of object.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have eagerly initialized the `Prefix` property of your model:

```
ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(
    db.People.Include(p => p.Prefix), 
    "PersonID", 
    "FullName", 
    personsalary.EmployeeID
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In People class, mark the property Prefix as virtual. If you do so, the value of corresponding prefix will be loaded when you try accessing this value.

Answer suggested by Darin will also work. This is an alternative approach.